# Correct way to receive COM Events from LocalServer, in a C++ Win32 Windows Service

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, service, com

Context: Windows 7 64-bit with a 3rd party vendor-provided COM Server running as LocalServer(.exe). It has some interfaces, methods, and also fires some events, in response to some hardware events. The Sample SDK applications provided work perfectly fine.

There is a need now, for a Windows Service written in C/C++, to receive these events.

Given that Windows Services run in Session_0 and the LocalServer is out of process, and hence runs in Logged-in User's Session_x session, how would one enable the processing of these COM Events, from within the Service?

Is it even possible, given Windows's strict security restrictions and goals behind session_0 based Windows Services?

If so, any ideas?